# How do I add JavaScript DOM API to my Polymer element?

Tags: polymer

I want my element to have specific JavaScript API. For example like `HTMLInputElement` that have `checked` property, I want my element to have a property that you can only set binary values to it and I have callbacks to changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This described in detail in the [documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#propertiesmethods).

Properties and methods are defined on the element's `prototype` using the `Polymer()` constructor.

```
Polymer('my-element', {
  name: 'Mohsen',
  isChecked: false,
  isCheckedChanged: function() {
    console.log('I am checked?', this.isChecked);
  },
  ...
});
```

To define a property as boolean, make sure to [hint its type](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrhinting).

Use [`<prop>Changed`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers) watchers to be notified when the `<prop>` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was useing `$0` in Chrome console to see my methods and properties. It doesn't work with selecting element in element panel and quering from `$0`, but if I use `querySelector` it works! `$0` works in Canary though

Comment: Now question is, how do I hide my methods from public API?

Comment: See http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#autocomplete and  http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#static